# Firefox bug in jQueryUI when Autocomplete is used in Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
#sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
.ui-autocomplete-loading {
background: white url('images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<ul id="sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags" />
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
 var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
```

Please refer to http://jsfiddle.net/85Z92/ in Firefox.

You will find that when Autocomplete is used to inside sortable, the input field cannot be clicked. But clicking the label is fine. If there is no label, then you can't click on the input field.

In Chrome/Safari, it works fine.

How to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Side-note: label and input are not valid directly children of `ul`. Won't fix your issue, but wrapping those inside a list item will at least be valid html.

Comment: For some reason, I must wrap it inside `ul`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/85Z92/3/

Just removed

```
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
```

And it got fixed.

Comment: Yes, `disableSelection` is deprecated and shouldn't be used for new code. It `preventDefault` for `mousedown` when `selectstart` is not available, causing the bug.